# Oracle Ordered Update Better Approach / Latch Free Wait Event

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

In our solution, we have to update a row assigning a value from a sequence. This update should respect an specific order, so, we used the following approach:

```
PROCEDURE P_RID_SELLERS_RETAIL (pCustomerID IN NUMBER, pCompanyID IN NUMBER)
IS
  CURSOR SYNC_CURSOR
  IS
       SELECT RECORD_ID
         FROM SALES_SCH.SYNC_SELLERS_RETAIL
        WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = pCustomerID AND COMPANY_ID = pCompanyID AND RECORD_ID < 0
     ORDER BY RECORD_ID;

  TYPE RECORD_ID_AAT IS TABLE OF SALES_SCH.SYNC_SELLERS_RETAIL.RECORD_ID%TYPE
     INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  L_RECORD_ID_AAT   RECORD_ID_AAT;
BEGIN
  OPEN SYNC_CURSOR;

  LOOP
     FETCH SYNC_CURSOR BULK COLLECT INTO L_RECORD_ID_AAT LIMIT 100000;

     EXIT WHEN L_RECORD_ID_AAT.COUNT = 0;

     FORALL i IN L_RECORD_ID_AAT.FIRST .. L_RECORD_ID_AAT.LAST
        UPDATE SALES_SCH.SYNC_SELLERS_RETAIL
           SET RECORD_ID = RECORD_ID.NEXTVAL
         WHERE RECORD_ID = L_RECORD_ID_AAT (i);

     COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE SYNC_CURSOR;
END;
```

Sometimes, when there is large amount of data do be update (large = more than 1 million of rows), we start dealing with performance issues, mainly Latch Free Wait event.

Do you know any other approach to do an ordered update that would be better than that?

Thanks a lot!